# so i have view which is being rendered on another page through ajax request but the javascript or jquery in it doesn't works

Tags: laravel

`here is the ajax request (

```
function getTaskdetails(taskId) {
fetch(`/tasks/${taskId}`, {
                                    method: 'GET',
                                    headers: {
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                                    },
                                })
                                .then(response => {
                                    if (response.ok) {
                                        return response.text(); // Assuming the response is HTML
                                    } else {
                                        console.error('Failed to fetch task details:', response.status, response.statusText);
                                        throw new Error('Failed to fetch task details');
                                    }
                                })
                                .then(html => {
                                    document.getElementById('custom-sidebar').innerHTML = html;
                                })
                                .catch(error => {
                                    console.error('Error:', error);
                                });
                            }
```

)
and here is the view which is being rendered (

```
<script>
    function MultiSelectTag(e, t = { shadow: !1, rounded: !0 }) {
        console.log("MultiSelectTag called"); 
        var n = null, d = null, l = null, a = null, s = null, i = null, o = null, c = null, r = null, u = null, p = null, v = null;
        var m = new DOMParser;

        function h(e = null) {
            for (var t of (v.innerHTML = "", d)) {
                if (t.selected) {
                    !w(t.value) && f(t);
                } else {
                    const n = document.createElement("li");
                    n.innerHTML = t.label;
                    n.dataset.value = t.value;
                    e && t.label.toLowerCase().startsWith(e.toLowerCase()) ? v.appendChild(n) : e || v.appendChild(n);
                }
            }
        }

        function f(e) {
            const t = document.createElement("div");
            t.classList.add("item-container");
            const n = document.createElement("div");
            n.classList.add("item-label");
            n.innerHTML = e.label;
            n.dataset.value = e.value;

            const l = (new DOMParser).parseFromString('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="item-close-svg">\n
                <line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line>\n
                <line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line>\n
                </svg>', "image/svg+xml").documentElement;

            l.addEventListener("click", (t => {
                d.find((t => t.value == e.value)).selected = !1;
                g(e.value);
                h();
                E();
            }));

            t.appendChild(n);
            t.appendChild(l);
            o.append(t);
        }

        function L() {
            for (var e of v.children) {
                e.addEventListener("click", (e => {
                    d.find((t => t.value == e.target.dataset.value)).selected = !0;
                    r.value = null;
                    h();
                    E();
                    r.focus();
                }));
            }
        }

        function w(e) {
            for (var t of o.children) {
                if (!t.classList.contains("input-body") && t.firstChild.dataset.value == e) {
                    return !0;
                }
            }
            return !1;
        }

        function g(e) {
            for (var t of o.children) {
                if (!t.classList.contains("input-body") && t.firstChild.dataset.value == e) {
                    o.removeChild(t);
                }
            }
        }

        function E() {
            for (var e = 0; e < d.length; e++) {
                n.options[e].selected = d[e].selected;
            }
        }

        n = document.getElementById(e);

        (function () {
            d = [...n.options].map((e => ({ value: e.value, label: e.label, selected: e.selected })));
            n.classList.add("hidden");

            (l = document.createElement("div")).classList.add("mult-select-tag");
            (a = document.createElement("div")).classList.add("wrapper");
            (i = document.createElement("div")).classList.add("body");
            t.shadow && i.classList.add("shadow");
            t.rounded && i.classList.add("rounded");

            (o = document.createElement("div")).classList.add("input-container");
            (r = document.createElement("input")).classList.add("input");
            r.placeholder = `${t.placeholder || "Search..."}`;
            (c = document.createElement("div")).classList.add("input-body");
            c.append(r);

            i.append(o);

            (s = document.createElement("div")).classList.add("btn-container");
            (u = document.createElement("button")).type = "button";
            s.append(u);

            const e = m.parseFromString('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">\n
                <polyline points="18 15 12 21 6 15"></polyline></svg>', "image/svg+xml").documentElement;
            u.append(e);

            i.append(s);
            a.append(i);
            (p = document.createElement("div")).classList.add("drawer", "hidden");
            t.shadow && p.classList.add("shadow");
            t.rounded && p.classList add("rounded");
            p.append(c);
            v = document.createElement("ul");
            p.appendChild(v);
            l.appendChild(a);
            l.appendChild(p);
            n.nextSibling ? n.parentNode.insertBefore(l, n.nextSibling) : n.parentNode.appendChild(l);
        })();

        h();
        L();
        E();

        u.addEventListener("click", (() => {
            p.classList.contains("hidden") && (h(), L(), p.classList.remove("hidden"), r.focus());
        }));

        r.addEventListener("keyup", (e => {
            h(e.target.value);
            L();
        }));

        r.addEventListener("keydown", (e => {
            if ("Backspace" === e.key && !e.target.value && o.childElementCount > 1) {
                const e = i.children[o.childElementCount - 2].firstChild;
                d.find((t => t.value == e.dataset.value)).selected = !1;
                g(e.dataset.value);
                E();
            }
        }));

        window.addEventListener("click", (e => {
            l.contains(e.target) || p.classList.add("hidden");
        }));
    }
</script>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        new MultiSelectTag('assigned_to');`your text`
    });
</script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="{{ route('tasks.update', $task->id) }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Title" name="title" class="form-control" id="title"
                    value="{{ $task->title }}" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <textarea placeholder="Description" name="description" class="form-control" id="description"
                    required>{{ $task->description }}</textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="start_date">Start Date</label>
                        <input type="date" name="start_date" class="form-control" id="start_date"
                            value="{{ $task->start_date }}" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="end_date">End Date</label>
                        <input type="date" name="end_date" class="form-control" id="end_date"
                            value="{{ $task->end_date }}" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="project_id">project_id</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="project_id" name="project_id">
                    @foreach ($projects as $project)
                    <option value="{{ $project->id }}">{{ $project->title }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="estimated_hours">Estimated Hours</label>
                        <input type="number" name="estimated_hours" class="form-control" id="estimated_hours"
                            value="{{ $task->estimated_hours }}" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="status">Status</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
                            <option value="Todo">Todo</option>
                            <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                            <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                            <option value="Need Help">Need Help</option>
                            <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="task_members">Task Members</label>
                <select name="assigned_to[]" id="assigned_to" multiple>
                    @foreach ($users as $user)
                    @if (in_array($user->id, $task->assignedToIds()))
                    <option value="{{ $user->id }}" selected>{{ $user->name }}</option>
                    @else
                    <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                    @endif
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Task</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

) so the view renders fine but the script in it which for multiple select is not working

i tried to place the script on the main view where the other view is being called but doing so retuns me msg in console "MultiSelectTag called" plus an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'options')"  `